# How to install a plugin manually in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am unable to use `Composer` and thus have to install [CakePDF plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf) manually, but following examples from official CakePHP documentation does not seem to work.

So here is installation flow that I have followed:

1.) Copied the plugin to `app/plugins/CakePdf`

2.) Updated the app's `composer.json` file, like following:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
            "CakePdf\\": "./plugins/CakePdf/src",
            "CakePdf\\Test\\": "./plugins/CakePdf/tests"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Test\\": "tests",
        "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests"
        "CakePdf\\": "./plugins/CakePdf/src",
        "CakePdf\\Test\\": "./plugins/CakePdf/tests"
    }
}
```

3.) Loaded the plugin in `bootstrap.php`:

```
Plugin::load('CakePdf', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true, 'autoload' => true]);
```

4.) Added router extensions:

```
Router::extensions(['pdf']);
```

5.) Tried a very simple sample from plugin's doc:

```
$cakePdf = new CakePdf(array(
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
    'pageSize' => 'A4',
    'orientation' => 'portrait'
)); 

$html = '<html><head><body><p>Pdftest</p></body></head></html>';

$rawPdf = $CakePdf->output($html);
```

However the code breaks at the first line and the following error message is provided:

```
Class 'App\Controller\CakePdf' not found
```

I would really appreciate any help or guidance for how a plugin should be installed manually.

If there is any other information that I need to provide, just ask.

Comment: Simply updating composer.json won't do any good. You have to run `composer update` after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because inside `vendor/composer/` you can see some `autoload_*.php` files. These files hold the paths to load your classes. I think no one can safely tell you what to update and where in these files.

So you have two solutions:

1 - Copy `composer.json` on a local machine and run `composer update`. Then move the files created inside your app. I would suggest to take a backup before. Most probably the things that you will have to move are:

```
 vendor/
 composer.json
 composer.lock
```

2 - Start updating the files inside `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php` with the paths from the plugin. Most probably you will only need to update the following two files:

`vendor/cakephp-plugins.php` and `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`. Personally I wouldn't choose the second solution I am just adding it as an alternative just in case.

Comment: Your comment is useful. Just needs to add that we need to update this command in particular plugin rather than root folder.