# Plugin that uploads a new plugin and updates composer.json in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakephp3 so guide me if I am going wrong.
I have a written a plugin that takes a zip file of plugin as an input, unzips it and uploads it to the plugins folder.

The problem is, the plugin name is needed to be add in `comsposer.json` and loaded in `bootstrap.php`. And there is an additional step to perform that I have to run `composer dump-autoload` in order to get the plugin working. And if these steps are not performed, `cakephp3` gives error:

```
Error: Create the class FileUploaderController below in file: src\Controller\FileUploaderController.php
```

Till now, I have tried doing these steps manually and the plugin works fine. I want to know whether I am in right direction? if yes, then how to perform the above steps through code.

The tasks I want to perform through code are:

1. **Update Composer.json**
2. **Load plugin in bootstrap.php**
3. **Run command or get equivalent functionality to `composer dump-autoload`**

Any help would be appreciated. :)

**Update:1**
 I have came across the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163204/how-to-install-a-plugin-manually-in-cakephp-3) that also uses manual method. But I want to do it through code.

**Update 2**
I have found a way to perform `composer dump-autoload`. It can be done like this:

```
shell_exec('composer dump-autoload');
```

But I still want to know if it the right way or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out the solution to my problem. The plugin had to be loaded in `Bootstrap.php` with `autoload` parameter `true`.

No composer.json is to be edited and no command is to be executed.

I just added the following function to my controller that updates the `bootstrap.php` with `autoload=true`

```
function modifyBootstrap($plugin)
{
    $bootstrap = new File(ROOT . DS . 'config' . DS . 'bootstrap.php', false);
    $contents = $bootstrap->read();
    if (!preg_match("@\n\s*Plugin::loadAll@", $contents)) {
        $autoload = "'autoload' => true, ";
        $bootstrap->append(sprintf(
            "\nPlugin::load('%s', [%s'bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => true]);\n",
            $plugin,
            $autoload
        ));
    }
}
```

Once I performed this step, any plugin uploaded through my plugin works like a dream.